# CSS border property using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to figure out how to add border properties to an element using jQuery.

For example, I read that jQuery doesn't support the CSS property border-width. Instead, I should declare a variable (i.e. var borderWidth = .css("border-width");, and call the variable in a statement. But it's not working as expected.

Another side issue is, JSHint keeps telling my var's are missing ";", but they're clearly there.

```
var borderTop = .css("border-top-width");
var borderTopColor = .css("border-top-color");
```

The markup is simple:

```
<ul class="nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#">List View</a>

</li>
<li class="next"><a href="#">Map View</a>

</li>
```

Check out my Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bkmills1/ZaL8Z/1/).

Any assistance, as always, is appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: There are a lot of problems with your script.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Incomplete knowledge is a dangerous thing. "css()" is a jQuery function which needs to be applied on elements. But here you aren't using any element for CSS. Read documentation carefully before you try anything.

Comment: _"I read that jQuery doesn't support the CSS property border-width"_. Utter nonsense. You should read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to see what jQuery can and can't do: `Also, jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns the correct value for both .css( "background-color" ) and .css( "backgroundColor" ).`

Comment: Your fiddle is throwing syntax errors right out of the gate because of what you're trying to do to specify your initial variables.

Comment: @Chris Marasti-Gerog, I have a UL which, when clicked, I want to control the border properties (width, color) for an li with a specific class name that "contains" specific text.

Because the class names change based on what is selected (active/next), I can't simply use :first-child or :last-child, which is why I'm using the :contains() selector.

Comment: @user3582095 Your script doesn't handle clicks at all.  You're best off defining the styles as CSS classes, and using jQuery to add/remove classes to elements based on clicks.  Using `:contains()` is probably not actually the best thing here, but you haven't given us your actual problem yet.  Given `var borderTop = .css("border-top-width");` and `if ('.nav-tabs')`, I'd suggest that you really need to step back and go through an intro to javascript-type book or site.  I recommend JavaScript: The Good Parts.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is nothing but a platform which help you to access css and javascript in fast and easy way. If you run the code to change css property of any element it means you're creating css of that element dynamically on run time. Almost every property of css and javascript can be accessed using jquery.

You can write your code in this way.

```
if ($('.nav-tabs:contains(li)')) {
$('.active').css('border-style','solid')
$('.active').css('border-color','red')
$('.active').css('border-width','10px')
}
```

Or here is the modification done in one condition of your code:

```
 //if class "active" contains "Map View"
if ($('.nav-tabs:contains(li)')) {
    $('.next:contains(Map View)').css({'border-style':'solid','border-top':'thick single #ff0000'})
$('.next').css('border-color','red')

    }
```

May this will help you. Please do the changes in the same way no need to take variables. The values you've provided  for different css properties are not correct. Please follow:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

It will help you in understanding the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZaL8Z/6/) that will get you started.

You can play around with the styling as you see fit, add a class, remove a class, etc.

I think some key issues are:

1. You can have two or more classes in the HTML element.
2. You often need to "remove a class" before you "add a class" so there won't be a conflict.
3. You can use .on('click',  or .click (.click won't let you access dynamically generated elements)
4. The 'alerts' I added are just to give you a point where you would jump/run another set of code.

JS

```
$listview = $('.listview');
$mapview = $('.mapview');

$listview.on('click', function(){
      $listview.removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
      $mapview.removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
      $listview.css("border", "4px solid green");
      $mapview.css('border', '0px solid green');
      alert("I'm showing you a list");
                                      });
$mapview.on('click', function(){
      $mapview.removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
      $listview.removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
      $mapview.css("border", "4px solid green");
      $listview.css('border', '0px solid green');
      alert("I'm showing you a map");
                                      });
```